# Rails ignoring render method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just starting with rails so I'm following the [getting started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on their website.

However, I'm stuck at the create method part.

So here is my actual code

**User controller**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end
    def signin
    end
    def create
      render plain: params[:user].inspect
   end
end
```

**User new view**

```
    <%= form_for :user, html: {role: "form", class: "col-md-6"}, url: user_index_path do |f| %>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Username", :class => "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", :class => "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password", :class => "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                <%= f.password_field :passwordbis, :placeholder => "Repeat password", :class => "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>

      <p>
        <%= f.submit :value => "Sign up", :class => "btn btn-success" %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
get "welcome/index"
root 'welcome#index'

get '/about'    => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'about'
get '/contact'  => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'contact'
get '/privacy'  => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'privacy'
get '/terms'    => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'terms'

resources :user do
  post 'signin'
end
```

The error I get:

```
Missing template user/create, application/create
```

I do not understand why the error message is still thrown whereas I put a render call in the create method. I'm pretty sure it's some silly beginner mistake, any help ?

*edit: The catch is that if I remove the create method, it complains about a missing create action, so I assume the method is called*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using render plain: 'some text with methods and variables'

You should be instead using:

```
render inline: code with ruby and such here.
```

inline allows the use of Ruby code, where plain: will only allow the use of plain text. (i.e. no Ruby)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

See the above as reference.

Comment: Thanks ! Is the doc outdated then ?

Comment: Looks it. Wrong actually, seeing as how the paragraph below it mentions render taking a hash with a key of text and value of params[:article].inspect

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your last sentence. You mean that the doc is rather wrong than outdated ?

Comment: Personally I've never really used the plain: or inline: options on render. I was more just mentioning that the paragraph below it is wrong, so maybe that's a sign that it could use some work. With what it is saying, the code would look like render text: params[:article].inspect No worries. Did changing it allow you to move on? It's nothing worth getting stopped in your progress. Hope it helped!

Comment: Yes, it helped me. In fact, I'm just starting with rails, so I try to follow the official getting started to have an overall look :)